# how to update column with null value?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

As i update column with null value, it gives me an error like this:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '00:00:00' in 'field list' (SQL: update `attendances` set `00:00:00` = 12:11:45 where (`studentid` = 4 and `date` = 2018-07-09))

**query**

```
DB::table('attendances')
    ->where(['studentid' => $singleData['id'], 'date' => $date])
    ->update([$data['out_am'] => $time]);
```

**my controller**

[image: [Image]]

Comment: Post your query builder code

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid sorry i edit my post now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a value as a field name. It should probably be something like this:

```
DB::table('attendances')
    ->where(['studentid' => $singleData['id'], 'date' => $date])
    ->update(['out_am' => $data['out_am']]);
```

Comment: $data['out_am'] is what i get in foreach.

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '00:00:00' in 'field list' (SQL: update `attendances` set `00:00:00` = 12:27:14 where (`studentid` = 4 and `date` = 2018-07-09))

Comment: Are you still using `->update([$data['out_am'] => $time]);`?

Comment: no sir. i try ->update([$time => $data['out_am']]); and still getting the same error

Comment: Ok, again there you're using a value as the column, you can't use a variable for the array index. If your column is named `out_am` in the table, then it has to be like this: `->update(['out_am' => $data['out_am']])` or `->update(['out_am' => $time])`.

Comment: You're doing it correctly in the `where` clause, just need to apply the same approach to the `update` clause. `->update(['table_column_name' => $valueToInsert])`

Comment: oopss sorry sir i get it.

Comment: how sir? sorry im not so much familiar with this site